# Matplotlib square boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a plot of two boxplots in the same figure. For style reasons, the axis should have the same length, so that the graphic box is square. I tried to use the `set_aspect` method, but the axes are too different because of their range
and the result is terrible.

Is it possible to have 1:1 axes even if they do not have the same number of points?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Axes.set_aspect](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html?highlight=set_aspect#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect) to do this if you set the aspect to the ratio of axes limits.  Here's an example:
[image]

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show

fig = figure()

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax0.set_xlim(10., 10.5)
ax0.set_ylim(0, 100.)
ax0.set_aspect(.5/100)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax1.set_xlim(0., 1007)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 12.)
x0, x1 = ax1.get_xlim()
y0, y1 = ax1.get_ylim()
ax1.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))

show()
```

There may be an easier way, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 3):

Try `axis('equal')`. It's been a while since I worked with matplotlib, but I seem to remember typing that command a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For loglog plots ( `loglog()` ) don't forget to use

```
ax1.set_aspect(log10(xmax/xmin)/log10(ymax/ymin))
```